# Exponential Family distribution with non-open natural parameter space?

Tags: exponential-family

Is there any example of canonical exponential family distribution with a natural parameter space, that is **not open**?

An $k$ dimensional canonical exponential family means having a p.d.f (w.r.t base measure $u(dx)$)$$\exp\{T'\eta\}c(\eta),$$
where $T\in\mathbb{R}^k$ is the sufficient statistic and $\eta$ is the natural parameter.

A natural parameter space is defined as $$\Xi=\left\{\eta\in\mathbb{R}^k: \int\exp\{t'\eta\}u(dt)<\infty\right\}$$

I wonder if there is any canonical exponential family distribution having $\Xi$ being a non-open set in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

By the way, this is NOT a duplicated question.